# Why getting high response time when downloading S3 object throgh PHP script on EC2 instance?

Tags: php, download, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to download Amazon S3 private object through my EC2 micro instance (Using undesigned.org.za S3 PHP Class). This is my script. Actually script is working, but some times it takes few seconds to start downloading. I'm not really confidant with headers I used. All suggestions are really appreciated.

My S3 bucket and EC2 instance (Currently its micro instance) in same region.

```
if (!class_exists('S3')) require_once '../include/S3.php';
$s3 = new S3("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    $fileX=filename.mp3;// File Name
    $bucket='mybucket';
    $uri="username/public/filename.mp3"; // File path inside bucket

    //undesigned.org.za S3 PHP Class

    $info = $s3->getObjectInfo($bucket, $uri);
    $file = S3::getAuthenticatedURL($bucket, $uri, 3600);

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='."\"$fileX\"");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=28800');
    header('Expires:' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T', strtotime('+8 hours')));
    header('Content-Length: '.$info[size]);
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
```

My Questions are,

1. Why I'm getting high response time?
2. Did I use correct headers ?
3. What is the best S3 PHP class to do this?

Comment: Sorry, but not a real question. "best way", requests for code reviews, etc... are not for this site. Try codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry Mark. I'm new to this site. I'm actually having issues with this code. I'll edit the question. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried comparing it with [AWSSDKforPHP](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/) libraries?